# number of times Brownian motion hits boundaries

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Any experts here please direct me to some appropriate keywords that I can search for. Consider a Brownian motion constrained to an upper and lower boundaries. Let's say I want to know that how many times it hits one of the two boundaries (let's say per unit time starting from stationary induced measure). How do I approach this problems?...

Comment: Perhaps local times?

Comment: As soon as it hits the boundary once, it immediately hits it infinitely many more times. So either the answer is just infinity or "how many" is not the right question.

Comment: This assumes that by "constrained" you mean "reflected at both boundaries". If you mean "conditioned to remain in the interval" then the answer is 0.

Comment: How do I prove that it hits immediately infinitely  many times just after hitting once?

Comment: @Bati No local times can be calculated it seems..... I wanted to know number of times